# Excel file opens but when ready to save the file is readonly

Tags: microsoft-excel, read-only

Here is the situation.
Windows Server Essentials 2012 R2 and windows 7 pro via domain.

Laptop user opens 6 excel files. next he goes home with the files open to work on them. when he comes back to the plant he tries to save the files but the files on the server say this:
\CVT\Shared Folders\Quality\Cole\inventory.xlsx' is read-only. To save a copy click ok then give the workbook a new name in the save as dialog box.

this is becoming a HUGE MESS as we now have 20-30 files all the same but with different file names becuase NOONE here can figure it out so they keep renaming the file names.

Answer (score 0):

If the worker has network access at home he will need to:

1. Save and close the file before he leaves the plant.
2. Connect to the network at home.
3. Open the file and work in it.
4. Save and close the file before leaving home.
5. Open the file again once back at the plant.

Without doing the above, or if there is no access to the internal network from home, the worker will have to save the file to their computer, work in it at home, and then save it over the old file when back at work.

Please note that both of these methods are not recommended if multiple people work in the same file because there will be version control issues, with many people overwriting the changes made by others.